# call python function from shell and get only the returned value

Tags: python, shell

How to get **only** the returned value from a function, in the below example, I want to get only `foorbar` and not `this is a test` in the bash shell.

```
$ cat foo.py
print "this is a test"
def bar():
    return "foobar"

$ output=$(python -c 'import foo;print foo.bar()')
$ echo $output
this is a test foobar
```

Comment: .... suppress stdout, then re-enable it only for that function call maybe?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend if you require for whatever reason the `print "this is a test"` section, you check if the file is being run itself, such as by checking the `__name__` property as follows:

**foo.py:**

```
def bar():
    return "foobar"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("this is a test")
```

This should mean that the only time "*this is a test*" is printed is when you call `python foo.py`, and not when foo is imported as a module.
Hope this helps!

Comment: in my case, I cannot modify foo.py, as its coming from different team, so I will have to do something from shell. thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the module as-is and get what you want, you need to suppress the module level string being printed by temporarily redirecting the STDOUT to someplace else (e.g. `None`, `/dev/null` or any other file descriptor as a dumping zone), and duplicate again to the original STDOUT once the `import` is done.

```
% cat spam.py
print("this is a test")
def bar():
    return "foobar"

% python3 -c 'import sys;sys.stdout=None;import spam;sys.stdout=sys.__stdout__;print(spam.bar())'
foobar

% out=$(python3 -c 'import sys;sys.stdout=None;import spam;sys.stdout=sys.__stdout__;print(spam.bar())')

% echo "$out"
foobar
```

Expanded form:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = None
import spam
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
print(spam.bar())
```

Comment: Ooh, I didn't realize that you could use `None` for `sys.stdout` without complaint from Python.

Comment: @kindall Funny thing is I also come to know this today :)

Comment: Well, since this obviates the need for my answer, I'll at least share my one-liner to create a dummy file-like class with a `write` method that doesn't do anything: `sys.stdout = type("DummyStdout", (object,), {"write": lambda self, s: None})()`

Comment: Thanks, but foo.py was written for python2, so it throws some error with python3, any solution with python2 is appreciated. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, where the desired output is the final line of the python's stdout, you can use `tail`:

```
output=$(python -c 'import foo;print foo.bar()' | tail -1)
```